# Regular way to encoding color in 32-bit uint? (RGBA? ARGB? BGRA?)

Tags: encoding, colors

A R/G/B/A color components can be encoded in a single uint value. But I'm confusing order of the each components. Of course, there is no law, but I want to know more regular or more compatible order to hardware acceleration API like OpenGL.

-- edit --

I'm asking about byte encoding order of each channels, not it's terms.

Answer (score 0):

... [And the winner is](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=argb&word2=rgba): RGBA.

ARGB is actually one that I've probably seen more often, but in terms of "support" or "performance" any of those will suffice. BGRA is somewhat less common, though.

Comment: @Jim: oops, must be the dyslexia playing up again... that's what I meant to enter into google fight :) But I still think ARGB more common than either of the other two.

Comment: So..., this means byte ordering of A-R-G-B right? Not R-G-B-A.